# How can i delete multiple nodes of a BST in c?

Tags: c, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

i have to delete some nodes of this BST

```
struct node {
    char *value;
    struct node *p_left;
    struct node *p_right;
    int usable;
};
```

the nodes that i have to delete are the ones with `usable` set to 0.
my question is, is it possible to make a sweep of the tree and delete all the nodes with usable == 0? all the resources i found online are about deleting a node containing a certain key, i tried to apply those but they didn't work

--edit:
the remove node function that i implemented was fine:

```
struct node* deleteNode(struct node* root, char *key) {
    if (root == NULL)
    {
        return root;}
    int cmp_result = strcmp(key, root->value);
    if (cmp_result < 0)
        root->p_left= deleteNode(root->p_left, key);
    else if (cmp_result>0)
        root->p_right= deleteNode(root->p_right, key);
    else{
        if (root->p_left==NULL) {
            struct node *temp = root->p_right;
            free(root);
            return temp;
        } else if(root->p_right==NULL){
            struct node *temp = root->p_left;
            free(root);
            return temp;
        }
        struct node* temp = minValueNode(root->p_right);
        strcpy(root->value, temp->value);
        root->p_right= deleteNode(root->p_right, temp->value);
    }
    return root;
}
```

the problems arose because i called this function while traversing the tree, changing the structure of the tree while i'm using it

```
void pos2(struct node *head, char exactchar, int n)
{
    if( head != NULL ) {
        pos2(head->p_left, exactchar, n);

        if (head->value[n]!=exactchar){
            head = deleteNode(head, head->value);}

        pos2(head->p_right, exactchar, n);
    }
}
```

like this function that deletes a node if it has a word without a determined char in a determined position in it

Comment: You say you've tried applying your research: what have you tried?

Comment: previously i tried deleting immediately the nodes instead of flagging them and deleting later, but i entered in a hellhole of segfault from which i can't escape. i have so changed my approach to 1)flag the nodes i want to remove 2) make a sweep of the tree to remove the nodes i have flagged. I am not capable to produce a solution tho

Comment: Don't tell. _Show_ us the code you tried. :)

Comment: "Didn't work" is not an adequate description of the problem

Answer (score 1):

> is it possible to make a sweep of the tree and delete all the nodes with usable == 0?

Of course.

> all the resources i found online are about deleting a node containing a certain key, i tried to apply those but they didn't work

I have no idea what, specifically, you tried.  However, algorithms aimed at deleting the node having a specific key clearly do not solve the problem you have posed.  They will use the BST-ness of the tree to efficiently find the specific node to delete, if it is present, and delete just that node.

Since your flag does not have a functional relationship with the keys on which the BST is ordered, you need to traverse the whole tree and delete every node you find that satisfies your criterion for doing so.  Operationally, I would probably structure that as a depth-first traversal with post-order deletions (that is, consider whether to delete a given node *after* processing both its subtrees).